# How to call current level of a virtual method in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Let suppose two classes:

```
Parent = class
public
  procedure virtFunc(); virtual;
  procedure other();
end;

Child = class(Parent)
public
  procedure virtFunc(); override;
end;
```

Usually, calling `virtFunc` on a `Child` instance from anywhere will call the `Child` implementation of that method. However, sometimes it's useful to call the same level implementation:

```
procedure Parent.other();
begin
  virtFunc(); // I want to call Parent.virtFunc(), not Child.virtFunc()
end;
```

---

**What did I tried?**

`Parent(Self).virtFunc()`

`(Self as Parent).virtFunc()`

And obviously, I could (but this is not the question):

- rename them differently (childFunc vs parentFunc),
- remove the `virtual`.

---

**How to call the current level (non-polymorphic) version of a method in Delphi?**

For those who know c++, I would like some equivalent to `Parent::virtFunc()`

Comment: Are you sure you ask this for the base class (you wrote `procedure Parent.other();`) and not for the child class (you then mean `procedure Child.other();`)?

Comment: @AmigoJack: That is correct: calling the parent from the child can easily be done with `inherited`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the only way to do this is to:

1. Implement `Parent.virtFunc` by a call to a non-virtual method in `Parent`.
2. When you want to call `virtFunc` in a non-polymorphic way you call that non-virtual method rather than calling `virtFunc`.

Answer (score -1):

ONE

```
    {
     получить доступ к предкам даж если их методы виртуальные
     дети выполнятся не будут

     пример
         TV1 = class
            public
             A:integer;
             function GetH:integer;virtual;
         end;

         TV2 =class (TV1)
            public
              B:integer;
             function GetH:integer;override;
         end;
        //////////////////////////////////
        function TV2.GetH:integer;
        begin
          Result:=inherited +B;
        end;
        function TV1.GetH:integer;
        begin
          Result:=A;
        end;
        procedure TForm1.Panel1Click(Sender: TObject);
          var I:TV2;
          s:integer;
        begin

           I:=TV2.Create;
           I.B:=2;
           I.A:=1;

           //хочу получить доступ с формы к TV1.GetH что бы  TV2.GetH не выполнялся
           AmVirtual<TV2,TV1>.G(I,
           procedure(X2:TV1)
           begin
            s:=X2.GetH;
           end);

           showmessage( s.ToString);  // >> 1
           showmessage( I.GetH.ToString);//>> 3
           I.free;
        end;
    }
  type
   AmVirtual<T1,T2:class> =class
    type
     TProc = reference to procedure (X2:T2);
      class procedure G(X1:T1;Proc:TProc);static;
   end;
class procedure AmVirtual<T1,T2>.G(X1:T1;Proc:TProc);
 type
 PClass = ^TClass;
 var
 ClassOld: TClass;
begin
 ClassOld := PClass(X1)^;
 PClass(X1)^ := T2;
 try
   proc(X1 as T2);
 finally
  PClass(X1)^ := ClassOld;
 end;
end;
```

TWO

```
type
 TProc = procedure (arg:TObject) of object;
var Proc: TProc;

begin
  TMethod(Proc).Data:=self;
  TMethod(Proc).Code:=@TParent.Proc;
  Proc(Sender);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).